# How to use hexo to pop up a picture

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox, hexo

I changed the hexo (landscape theme) sharing button, the following is the code.
(HEXO\themes\landscape\layout_partial\article.ejs)

```
<article id="<%= post.layout %>-<%= post.slug %>" class="article article-type-<%= post.layout %>" itemscope itemprop="blogPost">
  <div class="article-meta">
    <%- partial('post/date', {class_name: 'article-date', date_format: null}) %>
    <%- partial('post/category') %>
  </div>
  <div class="article-inner">
    <%- partial('post/gallery') %>
    <% if (post.link || post.title){ %>
      <header class="article-header">
        <%- partial('post/title', {class_name: 'article-title'}) %>
      </header>
    <% } %>
    <div class="article-entry" itemprop="articleBody">
      <% if (post.excerpt && index){ %>
        <%- post.excerpt %>
        <% if (theme.excerpt_link){ %>
          <p class="article-more-link">
            <a href="<%- url_for(post.path) %>#more"><%= theme.excerpt_link %></a>
          </p>
        <% } %>
      <% } else { %>
        <!-- table of content -->
        <% if (post.toc == true){ %>
          <div id="toc" class="toc-article">
            <div class="toc-title">目录</div>
            <%- toc(page.content, {class: 'post-toc', list_number: false}) %>
          </div>
        <% } %>
        <%- post.content %>
      <% } %>
    </div>
    <footer class="article-footer">
      <!--
      <a data-url="<%- post.permalink %>" data-id="<%= post._id %>" class="article-share-link"><%= __('share') %></a>
      -->

      <div style="float: right">
        <a title="分享到新浪微博" class="article-share-weibo" target="_blank" href="http://service.weibo.com/share/share.php?url=<%- post.permalink %>"></a>
        <a title="分享到 QQ 空间" class="article-share-qq" target="_blank" href="https://sns.qzone.qq.com/cgi-bin/qzshare/cgi_qzshare_onekey?url=<%- post.permalink %>"></a>
        <a title="分享到微信" class="article-share-wechat" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.open('http://s.jiathis.com/qrcode.php?url=<%- post.permalink %>','QRCODE','width=200,height=200,directories=0,location=0,toolbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,status=0,scrollbars=0,titlebar=0');return false;"></a>
      </div>

      <% if (post.comments && config.disqus_shortname){ %>
        <a href="<%- post.permalink %>#disqus_thread" class="article-comment-link"><%= __('comment') %></a>
      <% } %>
      <%- partial('post/tag') %>

    </footer>
  </div>
  <% if (!index){ %>
    <%- partial('post/nav') %>
  <% } %>
</article>

<% if (!index && post.comments && config.disqus_shortname){ %>
<section id="comments">
  <div id="disqus_thread">
    <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="//disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
  </div>
</section>
<% } %>
```

Click on the third button will pop up a two-dimensional code picture (two-dimensional code picture is generated online), as below. You can also see the effect on the site.
[image: a windows pops up]
I would like to use fancybox pop up that picture, as below, how to do? I am not good at web development and receive all the better ways.
[image: want to display a qrcode image]

Comment: I forgot to add the address, You can also see the effect on the site: https://knightmobile.github.io

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing you need to do is to add the class `fancybox` to your anchor and replace the value of the `href` attribute with the URL of the QRCode image (currently in the `window.open` function) like:

```
<a class="fancybox article-share-wechat" 
   href="http://s.jiathis.com/qrcode.php?url=https://knightmobile.github.io/2017-07-25/bing-included/','QRCODE','width=200,height=200,directories=0,location=0,toolbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,status=0,scrollbars=0,titlebar=0">
</a>
```

Then, bind that *class* to fancybox in your jQuery code like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        // API options
        type: 'image'
    }); // fancybox
}); // ready
```

See a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jms83g3d/)** using fancybox v2.1.5

You may eventually want to use fancybox v3, see **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8szgfqkv/)** too

**NOTE**: I am using the rendered html on both demos. You may need to tweak your code to reflect the proper *class* and `href`

Of course, you need to include in your page the proper JS and CSS fancybox files of the version you are using. Please refer to the plugin documentation

Comment: Your information is useful to me, but my web knowledge is too short. I have given up. Thank you